# T-SQL ordering data in hierarchy query from parents to children

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have hierarchical data with parents and children together with positions.

Sample:

```
create table groups 
(
    Child varchar(1), 
    Parent varchar(1), 
    Position int
);

insert into groups (Child, Parent, Position) 
values ('A', NULL, 1),
       ('B', 'A', 1),
       ('C', 'B', 1),
       ('D', 'B', 2),
       ('E', NULL, 2),
       ('F', NULL, 3),
       ('G', 'F', 1),
       ('H', 'G', 1),
       ('I', 'G', 2),
       ('J', 'F', 2),
       ('K', 'J', 1),
       ('L', 'J', 2);
```

Each group and subgroup has it own position starting with 1, e.g.:

- all parents have positions: 1 - x
- all children with parent "A" have positions: 1 - x
- all children with parent "N" have positions: 1 - x

I need to order the query the way that the children of the parents always come between parents ascending, for example (added levels for better imagination):

```
Level|Child|Parent|Position
-----+-----+------+---------
  3  |  A  | NULL |   1
  2  |  B  |   A  |   1
  1  |  C  |   B  |   1
  1  |  D  |   B  |   2
  3  |  E  | NULL |   2
  3  |  F  | NULL |   3
  2  |  G  |   F  |   1
  1  |  H  |   G  |   1
  1  |  I  |   G  |   2
  2  |  J  |   F  |   2
  1  |  K  |   J  |   1
  1  |  L  |   J  |   2
```

This is my current code:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select Child, Parent, Position 
    from groups

    union all

    select t.Child, t.Parent, t.Position 
    from groups t
    join cte on t.Child = cte.Parent
)
select distinct * 
from cte 
order by Position
```

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f298d6b43dc5926edeabcd43148f534d)

Thank you

Comment: I've edited your question to include the DDL and DML of the sample data as well as your query.  A link to fiddle is great, but it can't be instead of posting proper sample data in the question itself. A lot of people are using SO at work and some websites might be blocked  or inaccessible for them.

Comment: To control the sort, you can add a `sort` column, like this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857908/822072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cte is a little messed up. Here's how I would do it:

```
;with cte as (
    select Child, Parent, Position As ParentPosition, Position, 1 As level 
    from groups
    where parent is null
    union all
    select t.Child, t.Parent, cte.ParentPosition, t.Position, level + 1
    from groups AS t
    join cte on t.Parent = cte.Child
)
select  * 
from cte 
order by ParentPosition, level, Position
```

Your cte's anchor part was all the records in the table, where in fact it should be just the records that has no parents (hence the `where parent is null`).
Also, I've added a column for the parent's position to enable sorting all the children of the same parent before the next parent, and I've added a level column to help order the children by distance from the main parent.

Results:

```
Child   Parent  ParentPosition  Position    level
A               1               1           1
B       A       1               1           2
C       B       1               1           3
D       B       1               2           3
E               2               2           1
F               3               3           1
G       F       3               1           2
J       F       3               2           2
K       J       3               1           3
H       G       3               1           3
I       G       3               2           3
L       J       3               2           3
```

[<kbd>Db<>Fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9792145be5da6454d2ee516a8d27e74d)